# Supress number version from InstanceID

Tags: sql-server, command-line-arguments, unattended-processing

I am installing SQL SERVER 2022 from command line with this command:

```
SETUP.exe /IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS="False" /ACTION="Install" /ROLE="AllFeatures_WithDefaults" /IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS="False" /SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE="False" /QUIET="False" /QUIETSIMPLE="True" /UpdateEnabled="True" /USEMICROSOFTUPDATE="False" /SUPPRESSPAIDEDITIONNOTICE="False" /UpdateSource="MU" /FEATURES=SQLENGINE,REPLICATION /HELP="False" /INDICATEPROGRESS="False" /INSTANCENAME="SQLMYINSTANCE" /INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" /INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server" /INSTANCEID="SQLMYINSTANCE" /SQLTELSVCACCT="NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$SQLMYINSTANCE" /SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" /INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Servicio de red" /AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled" /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" /FILESTREAMLEVEL="0" /SQLMAXDOP="0" /ENABLERANU="True" /SQLCOLLATION="Modern_Spanish_CI_AS" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\MSSQL$SQLMYINSTANCE" /SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT="True" /SECURITYMODE="SQL" /SAPWD="@rquer0" /SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT="1" /SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE="8" /SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH="64" /SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE="8" /SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH="64" /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="True" /TCPENABLED="0" /NPENABLED="0" /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled" /SQLMAXMEMORY="2147483647" /SQLMINMEMORY="0" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True" /SKIPRULES="RebootRequiredCheck"
```

This creates a directory like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.SQLMYINSTANCE\MSSQL
```

Is it possible to eliminate the number "16" just to make a more generic path? Maybe another param in command line or change an existing one?

Comment: Try `/INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16"` although unclear why you should care. You can find a list of instance directories in the registry, and it would make more sense to just use the default so everyone understands what's going on.

Comment: Charlieface because I can install other versions of engine and I need to restore a database after that with this command in a process:

sqlcmd -S DESKTOP-AE1GCOH\SQLMYINSTANCE -Q "RESTORE DATABASE MYDB64SQLCMD FROM DISK = 'C:\TEMP\MYDB32.bak' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, MOVE N'MYDB32' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.SQLMYINSTANCE\MSSQL\DATA\MYDB64SQLCMD.mdf', MOVE N'MYDB32_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.SQLMYINSTANCE\MSSQL\DATA\MYDB64SQLCMD.ldf';

So I can't specify the real directory, it must be a generic one in order the process will success always.

Comment: Why can't you just use `SELECT @path = SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath');` to get the path, and concat it with your file name, then just do `RESTORE DATABASE .... MOVE @logicalFile TO @physicalFile;` I think you are trying to hit a nail with an oversize hamme. You just simply don't need to change the path to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: it's usually bad practice anyway to put databases on c:\ drive, even worse in c:programfiles, or at least i haven't seen it in production environments i worked in

Comment: Charlieface I took the idea and I could achieve what I wanted to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just change the parameter `/INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16"`.

Why you would want to do this I don't know, it's a bad idea. Use standard folder names, then it's easy for others to understand the setup.

---

As far as your purported issue with running `RESTORE` statements, you can parameterize it, and use `SERVERPROPERTY()` to get the folder path (or just pass in an actual parameter). Instance names that are available on the machine can be got from the registry.

For example:

```sql
DECLARE @path nvarchar(261) = SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath');
DECLARE @mdfPath nvarchar(261) = CONCAT(@path, 'MYDB64SQLCMD.mdf');
DECLARE @ldfPath nvarchar(261) = CONCAT(@path, 'MYDB64SQLCMD.ldf');

RESTORE DATABASE MYDB64SQLCMD
FROM DISK = 'C:\TEMP\MYDB32.bak'
WITH
  REPLACE, RECOVERY,
  MOVE N'MYDB32' TO @mdfPath,
  MOVE N'MYDB32_log' TO @ldfPath;
```